# DNS, A Record set up, mail server on one server, site hosted on another

Tags: hosting, dns

I am taking control of a clients website for them from the previous developers.

I am not that familiar with A records and anything more than basic hosting set up, and a bit concerned I may break things so seeking some advice.

The mail is currently hosted on with the host easily, and I've been told the actual sites files are hosted on an external server which is controlled by the A record. Since the A record points to an external server.
I have set up a new cpanel account for the existing domain on my own VPS and would like to clarify that changing the A record IP address to that of my VPS would point the domain to my server hosting the new site.

Here is a screenshot of the existing DNS setup in the easily control panel.

http://wilford.gemnetworks.com/easily.png

Many thanks,

David

Comment: where's problem with that? A record will point to your new IP with your new site MX records will stay as is. where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change the ip of the A record if you want to change server